Validation of Assertion Regarding Parallel Vectors and Their Magnitudes
If $ \mathbf{u} \parallel \mathbf{v} $, $ |\mathbf{u}| = 2 $, and $ |\mathbf{v}| = 4 $, then prove that $ \mathbf{v} = 2\mathbf{u} $ or $ \mathbf{v} = -2\mathbf{u} $.
Aimin for contradiction: $ \mathbf{u} $ is parallel to $ \mathbf{v} $, $ |\mathbf{u}| = 2 $, $ |\mathbf{v}| = 4 $, and $ \mathbf{v} \neq 2\mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} \neq -2\mathbf{u} $. Consider $ \mathbf{u} = (0, 2) $ and $ \mathbf{v} = (0, 4) $. Note that $ \mathbf{v} = 2\mathbf{u} $. Is this a counterexample to the contradiction, thus proving the original statement true?

Unfortunately, no. What you need to prove is that given any $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ like that, they are parallel. You just exhibited a pair which happens to both satisfy the criteria and are parallel.

What is your definition of parallel vectors?

@blomp I tried to show a counterexample. Two parallel vectors such that v=2u, which is a counterexample to P and Not Q (contradiction)

You want to prove that for all $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$, if $ \mathbf{u} \parallel \mathbf{v} $, $ |\mathbf{u}| = 2 $, and $ |\mathbf{v}| = 4 $, then $ \mathbf{v} = 2\mathbf{u} $ or $ \mathbf{v} = -2\mathbf{u} $.
In a proof by contradiction, you would assume the negation of this statement, which is: there exists $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ such that $ \mathbf{u} \parallel \mathbf{v} $, $ |\mathbf{u}| = 2 $, $ |\mathbf{v}| = 4 $, $ \mathbf{v} \neq 2\mathbf{u} $, and $ \mathbf{v} \neq -2\mathbf{u} $.
Notice how the negation changes the "for all" in the original statement to "there exists." For "there exists" statements, there is no way to provide a counterexample, because one counterexample does not disprove a "there exists" statement. Counterexamples only disprove "for all" statements. Therefore, since the negation is a "there exists" statement, the example you gave is not a counterexample to the negation of the original statement and thus does not prove the statement.
Personally, I would not use proof by contradiction for proving this statement because I think there is a simpler way to prove it. Think about the definition of $ \mathbf{u} \parallel \mathbf{v} $, i.e. there exists some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{u}=c\mathbf{v}$ or $\mathbf{v}=c\mathbf{u}$, and then use the lengths of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ to figure out the possible values of $c$.

Thank you very much! I really didn't see a "for all" embedded in the original statement. Ignore my attempt to edit your answer
